# My code is not executing properly in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple grade program in which the user is prompted for a decimal grade and in return are given a letter grade. It just doesn't seem to work. When I place a number like .9 it gives me B. It gives me B for all inputs and when I test it with a number greater than 1, it gives me "B A D C".

```
try :
grade = raw_input("what is ur grade")
if grade > .8 < .9 :
            print "B"
if grade > .9 < 1.0 :
            print "A"
if grade > .6 < .7 :
            print "D"
if grade  > .7 < .8 :
    print "C"
if grade < .6 :
    print "F"
except :
if grade > 1.0 :
    print "enter numeric value"
```

Please Help me understand...

Comment: why would we want screenshots? why not put your code? in addition i dont actually see any screenshots...

Comment: You need to post the actual specific code that is yielding the wrong results.

Comment: Your conditions and expressions are all wrong. They will all evaluate to ``True`` e.g: ``if x < 10 > 3: ...`` will always evaluate to ``True`` where as what you want is: ``if 10 < x < 3: ...``

Comment: also looks like your indentation is wrong--indent after "try" and "except".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from  bisect import bisect
def grade(score, breakpoints=[60, 70, 80, 90], grades='FDCBA'):
        i = bisect(breakpoints, score)
        return grades[i] 

while True:
    try:
       grad = float(raw_input("what is ur grade")) *100
       print grade(grad)
       break
    except:
         print 'Enter Correct value'
```

explantion for your code:

```
grade = raw_input("what is ur grade")
```

here your `grade` type is always `string` you need to convert it into `float`

```
if grade > .8 < .9
```

i think your grade between .8 and .9

it can be done

```
if .8<grade<.9:
```

Comment: I love it! Never come across this in the std. lib -- seems quite fitting :)